# Xampp error, port 80 in use with PID 4 in virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache-http-server, port

I noticed there is a lot of information about port 80 errors with xampp, however, there is not much information about this error on virtualbox.

On my main computer, xampp works perfect. On my virtualbox being hosted from my main computer, I get an error saying

> problem detected port 80 in use by "unable to open process" with PID4
>   apache will not start without the configured ports free

What exactly am I supposed to do?

Can I have a separate network from my main computer? Or is there another way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box uses Port 80 to create connection between physical machine and virtual machine. You can switch these settings by going into Virtual box preferences. Disable the port till the time you use Xampp, re-enable it to work on virtual box.